# How do I change actors.maxPoolSize in scala from java?

Tags: java, scala, actor

So I have two bash scripts. One for calling the bytecode using the "scala" command, the other to call the same code using the "java" command. My problem is the following, when I use scala, I can see that I can get about 80 threads ( which I created, and shows in my "Task Manager" ) while when I use the java command, I only get about 20 threads created. instead of 80. What is the equivalent "define" option under java for actors.corePoolSize and actors.maxPoolSize?

These are my bash scripts.
The first has the following:

`JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1g" scala -cp bin com.mcmc5.Main -Dactors.corePoolSize=60 -Dactors.maxPoolSize=5000`

the second has:

`java -cp scala-library.jar:bin com.mcmc5.Main -Dactors.corePoolSize=60 -Dactors.maxPoolSize=5000 -Xmx1g`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can set System Properties in your application:

```
System.setProperty("actors.minPoolSize" , numberOfActors)
System.setProperty("actors.maxPoolSize" , numberOfActors)
System.setProperty("actors.corePoolSize", numberOfActors)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have defined your properties using `java` looks fine. Have you considered setting the `actors.minPoolSize` property? This is *exactly* how I configure my actor-based applications.